# ASP.NET DropDownList Selected Value With Enumeration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0, enums

I'm using the settings in an enumeration to populate a dropdownlist in ASP.NET 4.0. The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to set a selected value other than first item, it throws an error telling me it cannot have more than one option selected.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
Public Shared Function ConvertEnumToArray(ByVal enumType As System.Type, _
        Optional ByVal DefaultValue As String = "nodefault", _
        Optional ByVal PromptValue As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal PromptText As String = "") As ListItem()

        Dim itemSelected As Boolean = False
        Dim i As Int32 = 0

        If Not enumType.IsEnum Then
            Throw New Exception(String.Format("Type {0} is not an enumeration.", enumType.Name))
        End If

        'Dim itemValues() As Array = [Enum].GetValues(enumType)
        Dim fields As FieldInfo() = enumType.GetFields()
        Dim itemNames() As String = [Enum].GetNames(enumType)

        Dim arr(itemNames.Length + 1) As ListItem

        For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
            If Not field.Name.Equals("value__") Then
                Dim item As New ListItem(field.Name, field.GetRawConstantValue().ToString())
                If item.Value = DefaultValue And DefaultValue <> "nodefault" Then
                    item.Selected = True
                    itemSelected = True
                End If
                arr(i) = item
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next

        If PromptText <> "" Then
            Dim item As New ListItem(PromptText, PromptValue)
            If Not itemSelected Then
                item.Selected = True
            End If
            arr(i) = item
        End If

        Return arr

    End Function

    Dim arrExtraChargesOptions() As ListItem
    arrExtraChargesOptions = Enumerations.ConvertEnumToArray(GetType(Enumerations.MoneyRoomCourierExtraChargesOptions))

    For Each li As ListItem In arrExtraChargesOptions
        'since arrays double in capacity to store data, there may be nulls
        If Not li Is Nothing Then
            Me.drpMondayExtraCharges.Items.Add(li)
        End If
    Next

    Me.drpMondayExtraCharges.ClearSelection()
    Me.drpMondayExtraCharges.SelectedIndex = -1
    Me.drpMondayExtraCharges.Items.FindByValue(Courier.MondayExtraCharge.ToString()).Selected = True
```

Despite clearing the selected value in multiple ways, the first item remains selected resulting in the error as mentioned above.

Other items that might help explaining how I ended up with the code above:

- I'm setting the return type of the function to an array since that's the parameter type the AddRange function on the DropdownList.Items expects, but when I used that method, an exception resulted due to the NULLs in the array.
- Before adding the ClearSelection() and SelectedIndex = -1 lines, my setting the selected value (either through the FindByValue as above or just directly setting the SelectedValue) resulted in my desired selected value being ignored.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

EDIT: I misspoke above (bad memory): Setting the SelectedValue directly results is what results in it being ignored. It has nothing to do with ClearSelection Or SelectedIndex =1 as I stated in the second bullet up above.

Comment: A slight change I would also make is calling Clear on the List prior to adding the list items. i.e. Me.drpMondayExtraCharges.Items.Clear()

Comment: This is on the initial load of the page so the item list is clear until I add the items as above.

Comment: Gotcha I guess it's one of those things that I do out of habit to avoid duplicate list items. I tend to be a belt and suspenders type of guy.

Comment: @PaulSmithJr I tested your code, and it works fine. Which line throws exception? Please upload the code as minimum as possible. Otherwise, we won't be able replicate it.

Comment: When I use the code as above, I get the exception on the FindByValue line (the last one in the code snippet above). When I use "SelectedValue = value" in place of FindByValue, there's no error but the code has no effect on the actual SelectedIndex.

Comment: I should note that the error with FindByValue only occurs if the SelectedIndex is different than the first item in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue (and I didn't provide enough code for you to find it yourselves).

Basically, I had a dropdownlist for each day of the week and the list items returned by ConvertEnumToArray above were added to each of the dropdowns. As a result, the selected item was changed on all the dropdown since the same list items were on each dropdown. Adding them to the dropdown as New Listitems solved the problem.